# Does YCSB load only varchar data type to tables?

Tags: ycsb

I am using YCSB-0.14.0 with Cassandra binding. If I create a table by following the below specified format, the data gets loaded to the table.

```
    create table usertable (
    y_id varchar primary key,
    field0 varchar,
    field1 varchar,
    field2 varchar);
```

If I change the data type to int from varchar, YCSB does not load any data. The same result is observed if I alter the names (y_id, field0 etc). Is it mandatory to specify the same names and same data type? Doesn't YCSB load only integer data?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what generator you are using, default is uniform which returns varchar from a uniform distribution